# C# Error 1 'Flashloader.Controller' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#

I have an error in my code and could not figure out how to fix it.
Can you guys help me?

This is the code:

```
private void typelistbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Controller controller = GetCurrentController();
        if (controller == null)
        {
            // TODO velden leegmaken
        }
        else
        {
            Controller item = new Controller();

            textBox1.Text = controller.Lastfile;
            _comPortComboBox.SelectedItem = controller.Port;
            Baudratebox.Items.Add(item.Baudrate);
        }

    }
```

And this is the error

> Error 1   'Flashloader.Controller' does not contain a constructor that
>   takes 0 arguments

Comment: `new Controller()` is the problem, it needs a parameter, as your question stands it is impossible to give a better answer as noone knows what constructors controller has

Comment: Oke thank for youre comment i figured it out just before i read youre comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have no standard constructor defined or defined only a constructor that accepts parameters of any kind.

Comment: Still can't find out whats the problem